# Minimising root function through scipy.optimize

Tags: python, function, scipy, ode

I have code which estimates a parameter beta in an ODE system, given that all parameters are known other than beta and the peak of the 'epidemic' simulation, is 10% of the starting population. However, I realise solving the root might not always work to find the value. Is there any method of using scipy.optimize to find an alternate way of estimating this, by taking the squared difference of sum at the 10% peak, squaring the whole thing, then minimising that? This is the current code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from  scipy.optimize import root

def peak_infections(beta, days = 100):

    # Total population, N.
    N = 1000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    gamma = 1/7
    # A grid of time points (in days)
    t = np.linspace(0, days, days + 1)

    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ

    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T

    return np.max(I)/N

root(lambda b: peak_infections(b)-0.1, x0 = 0.5).x
```

Using `scipy.optimize(root(lambda b: peak_infections(b)-0.1, x0 = 0.5).x)` only returns a misuse of function error.

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------

I am wondering how this approach could be applied to if instead of having 10% of the peak as a key piece of information, I had a dataframe of weekly new numbers. How could a similar method be used to take that data into account in helping estimate beta? If we say

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now this is our data, rather than knowing the peak of the simulation is 10% of the N starting population. How can this be used to minimise and find a beta estimate?

-----EDIT 2-------

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

###############################################################################
##########                  WITH WEEKLY DATA
###############################################################################


#t = np.arange(0,84,7)
t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77+1)
d = {'Week': [t[7],t[14],t[21],t[28],t[35],t[42],t[49],t[56],t[63],t[70],t[77]], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#d = {'Week': t, 'incidence': [0,206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
#df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def peak_infections(beta, df):
 
    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    #weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()

    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    #reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
    gamma = 1/6 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points 
    t7 = np.arange(7,84,7)

    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t7, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ

    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t7, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T

    return np.max(I)/N

def residual(x, df):

    # Total population,  N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df) - incidence) ** 2)

x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead").x
print(res)
```

Comment: edit your question and  fix the indentation. right now your code doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Your code isn't working right now. Please [edit] it so that it can be reproduced and checked.

Comment: Please see the edited and corrected layout for the code.

Comment: I tried your code. It is not returning any error, but running and finding the root successfully. However, I have proposed an alternate solution using `minimize`.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan Hello, I remember this post you were able to provide assistance on, I have a query regarding this same framework but for a slightly different root function example, I was wondering if you may be able to assist with here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462834/callibrating-a-basic-ode-system-using-scipy-optimise-or-minimise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

One approach would be as follows:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def residual(x):
    return (peak_infections(x) - 0.1) ** 2

x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, method="Nelder-Mead", options={'fatol':1e-04})
print(res)
```

This is right now giving almost the same answer as the root method you posted but works as an alternative.

### Edit

As per the discussion in the comment section of this answer, and according to the edit to you question, I propose the following solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from  scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd

d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def peak_infections(beta, df):

    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()

    # Total population, N.
    N = 1000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    gamma = 1/7 * 7 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points (in days)
    t = np.linspace(0, weeks[-1], weeks[-1] + 1)

    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ

    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T

    return I/N

def residual(x, df):

    # Total population, N.
    N = 1000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df)[1:] - incidence) ** 2)

x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead", options={'fatol':1e-04})
print(res)
```

Here, I calculate the ODE system for 11 weeks and compare the result directly with the 11 incidence values from the provided dataframe. After the squared difference (element-by-element), a sum is taken and that sum is minimized. The result, however, is not very promising.

Comment: Thank you for the response Muhammad. Please see my edit. I am wondering how this approach could be applied to if instead of having 10% of the peak as a key piece of information, I had a dataframe of weekly new numbers. How could a similar method be used to take that data into account in helping estimate beta?

Comment: So you want to minimize _beta_ for every weak’s incidence? And want to do it collectively for all the weeks in one optimization? Meaning one optimized _beta_ value for all weeks?

Comment: ideally, it would one optimized beta for all weeks together (i.e. not one beta for every week). Essentialy, I was hoping this would be possible basically the same way you proposed before, however now the historical data we have to estimate beta, is this weekly data (rather than before we know the 10% information)

Comment: So now you want to derive the differential equations w.r.t. weeks (and not days) and instead of 0.1, the incidence of each week would be the target peak? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Mostly, however, wouldn't it be possible to keep the ODE system the same? I wish to still estimate beta, with the same ODE system, all the other parameters. However, instead of knowing that the peak of infection is 10% of the starting population, we now have actual weekly data. So, we wish to find the value of beta that would *best fit* that data in the data frame, if that makes sense?

Comment: i.e., what value of beta would give a trajectory curve like the one if we plotted that data from `df`

Comment: That makes sense. Firstly, the ODE system will remain the same but instead of days, we should differentiate the ODEs w.r.t. weeks as we have data in weeks. Or can we say that Week 1 is day 7, Week 2 is day 14, and so on? Because if we want to fit the data in the data frame, we must differentiate the ODE system according to the independent variable, which is present in the data frame.

Comment: Secondly, in the current setup, you are getting the highest peak (from the calculation of 100 days) and dividing it with the population (`np.max(I)/N`). If we want to fit the data, we must calculate the peak (divide it by _N_) and return it (not take `np.max`), and then it can be compared with the incidence's value of the relative Week. In the end, all of the calculated values (of 11 weeks) can be compared with 11 calculated peaks. If you agree, I will try to edit my answer to propose a solution.

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail on the head as far as the logic goes. I am just confused on implementing the syntax. Do you have an idea of how it could be done with the code?

Comment: Is this something that could be implemented, do you think?

Comment: I have edited my answer. The result, however, is not very promising. Please try the code and see if you can spot something. I have implemented the logic. Maybe I am missing something. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your code! I am trying to optimise it now. I tried changing the weeks to days in my original model, however I just realised this weekly data was for N = 100,000. So, I changed the values of N to 100,000. However, the results still seem troublesome. I am not sure where the issue may be either.

Comment: Your welcome. Please check that there is also _N_ variable in the residual function. But that wont change much. I guess, you need to look for something in the model. Or may be something is wrong with the approach.

Comment: I think your approach is very much correct. its now a matter of tuning it in sync.

Comment: Following on from this, I was interested. Say if both beta *and* gamma was unknown. Is it possible to estimate gamma as well? How could it be implemented?

Comment: This is easily doable. You just need to pass `beta` and `gamma` to the `residual` function as a list, for e.g., `x0 = [0.5, 1/7]`. Inside the `peak_infections` function, unpack them as `beta = x[0]` and `gamma = x[1]`.

Comment: Im curious, how do you mean to unpack them? for example, i tried to list gamma as a function of x, however, x only appears in the residual function as an argument, so it cannot be used beforehand in peak_infections?

Comment: You should redefine the function as `peak_infections(x, df)`. Inside it, declare `beta = x[0]` and `gamma = x[1]`. Then for `minimize` (at the end of the code in my answer) pass `x0 = [0.5, 1/7]`. This way you can minimize both `beta` and `gamma`.

Comment: I see what you mean now, many thanks. Your approach appears to be very efficient, though the beta return estimates for this are slightly off. I still caannot figure out why. I have tweaked the time steps with which the ode was calculated, and the estimations got slightly closer, but still not quite there. It's bizarre as to why the estimations are not that close

Comment: Please see my edit 2 - do you know where this may be going wrong? I'm not sure what  else can be done to resolve the discrepancy in estimations. I have used a linspace time step to provide more accurate estimations, and removed `gamma = 1/6 * 6`. Additionally, I took the peak_infections function to return the np.max of I/N, rather than just I/N

Comment: Is there anything that i May have missed?

Comment: I guess you should return just `I/N` as now you want to compare the 11 peaks of data with the simulated 11 peaks of the model. If I understood you correctly.

Comment: See, for returning I/N the estimation is even more off than if I return the np.max of it

Comment: By returning `np.max(I/N)` you are comparing all of the 11 peaks in your incidence data every time with the highest peak delivered by `peak_infections`, which doesn't seem right to me as you want to compare all 11 computed peaks with 11 data peaks.